# How to enable a symlink in this case

Tags: ssh, folder, symbolic-link

I cannot categorize this question under ubuntu since it has nothing to do with it. But I know people here can definitely answer this. I login to one of my deployment boxes using SSH (no ubuntu here).

I am working in a tool called TeamCity which uses a folder called ".BuildServer" under home directory of the user. This folder may grow in size as the application runs but the current user is only given a limited amount of space. But the good thing this I got a folder access outside /home/deploy (deploy being the user here) folder. I now want to link this .BuildServer inside the /home/deploy directory to the other folder where I got permission for (meaning all the files should be re-routed to that directory)

Hope my question was clear, please help.

Comment: WHat have you tried already? I've not fully understood your question, do you want to move /home/user/.BuildServer to /home/deploy, and create the symlink /home/user/.BuildServer pointing to /home/deploy?

Comment: "deploy" is the username. So user and deploy are both the same. My sys admin has created a folder under root and has given me privileges to use it. I now want to re-route this /home/deploy/.BuildServer to that folder under root to /under_root/somfolder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've multiple options if you want to point `/home/deploy/.BuildServer` to an other directory, `/under_root/somefolder/`.

1) Create a symlink

```
ln -s /under_root/somefolder/ /home/deploy/.BuildServer
```

You should remove the .BuildServer directory first. Alternatively, you can move the `.BuildServer` directory to the new location:

```
mv /home/deploy/.BuildServer/ /under_root/somefolder/
```

Now run the `ln` command (see above).
Note: the user accessing `/under_root/somefolder/` should have access to that folder. Say the user is `deploy`, `somefolder` is owned by `deploy`, but `/under_root` is owned by some other user. You've now two possibilities: let `deploy` be a member of the group, used for `/under_root` and give add the execute bit to the group. (`chmod g+x /under_root`). The other case is that deploy cannot have the groupship over `/under_root`. In that case, make sure that anybody can dive in the directory: `chmod o+x /under_root`). This has to be done for every folder "above" `/under_root/somefolder`.

2) Bind mount

This can only be done by a user with root permissions (ask your sysadmin).

```
mount --bind /under_root/somefolder /home/deploy/.BuildServer
```

Using this method, there is no need to mess with the permissions of `/under_root`. Another advantage over symlinks is that this method works even if ssh chroots to `/home/deploy`.

Comment: +1 Recipe assuming admins got the permissions correctly: 'mv /home/deploy/.BuildServer /under_root/somefolder; ln -s /under_root/somefolder /home/deploy/.BuildServer'